# Changing class from disable to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some issues changing my class to active when adventwindow <= day, I want it to change the class from disable to active when true. If anyone could help that would be amazing!

```js
var day = 5;
var adventwindow = 1;

if (adventwindow <= day) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('disable').className = 'active';
}
```

```css
.door {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 70px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #91c1cc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-top: 2px #eee dashed;
  border-right: 2px #eee dashed;
  border-bottom: 2px #eee dashed;
  border-left: 1px #eee solid;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform-origin: 0 40%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  text-align: center;
}
a.disable {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
a.enable {
  pointer-events: auto
}
```

```html
<a class="disable" href="test">
  <div class="door">1</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements with the given class name. You can access the elements by index which start from 0.

`document.getElementsByClassName('disable')[0].className = 'active';`